# Image Behind Header and Offset on X and Y

Tags: css, center, transparent

Using CSS, how can I display an image behind some text and also offset it on both the X and Y axis?

I have a design that is 950px wide, so I'm wanting want this image to remain 'in sync' with the rest of the header by placing it in a container that is centered and also 950px wide.

My problem is that instead of the image being 'a layer behind' the header text, it is instead displaying the image in full and pushing the rest of the contents down.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**IMAGE ADDED FOR CLARIFICATION**
[image: Clarification Image]

Thanks,
Andy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Percentage values in your background positions in your css

```
.divName {
   background-position: 50%;

}
```

or using words like top or bottom ...

See the full list of values [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp)

UPDATE;

use the image as a background image instead of inline html image

```
<div class='content'>
    <p> Some content</p>
    <p> More content</p>
    .... even more content ...
</div>
```

Now the css:

```
div.content {
   background-image: url('image path');
   background-position: 50%;
}
```

This way the image will always be behind the content, and it will be in the center of the div.

Comment: Ok Cheers. But how would I get the content that comes after .divName to display on top of .divName?

Comment: @Andy ok, i added more explanation

Comment: Thanks. How about if the image was to extend beyond the original div? Like a 'background image overflow'. Is this possible?

Comment: the div size does not matter the image will always be centered

Comment: OK, but looking at [my diagram](http://i52.tinypic.com/warcbd.png), if I were to attach the background image to the 'Website Title' div, how would I achieve the left:-100px and top:-100px?

Comment: `background-position: -100px -100px; ` you can use this in ur css

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/MTB8Q/2/)?

Oke, that's more clear. Now I'm pretty sure [this is what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/MTB8Q/3/).

Answer (score 0):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/Fx5q3/

- http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/Adding_z-index

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
    background: rgba(127,127,127,0.7);

    position: relative
}
#behindImage {
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/150x150/f0f/fff) no-repeat;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: -90px;
    z-index: -1
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="behindImage"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis  volutpat blandit. Morbi bibendum pharetra bibendum. Fusce sit amet  lobortis odio. Proin ultricies, massa vel ornare fringilla, diam sem  convallis arcu, nec laoreet massa leo nec dolor. Nullam vel massa  ligula. Donec semper eros dapibus nibh dictum egestas ac nec libero.  Maecenas et fringilla augue. Phasellus imperdiet urna in sem scelerisque  adipiscing.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked a treat. So behind image is _absolute_ but only in relation to the containers _relative_ position. Interesting.